# Classifying based on an array of categories in Weaviate?

Tags: graphql, classification, weaviate

I'm trying to use the contextual classification on my data set of articles. The thing is, some of them belong to multiple "Categories", which are listed in an array. I would still like to classify my articles based on these categories but I'm not sure if that's possible or not? If so do I just proceed by making the dataType of my `Category` class an array of strings, and let the `category` property in my `Article` class have data type... string?

Answer (score 0):

The property you classify to, must be a reference property, so your class `Article` should have a property `ofCategories` - which points to a single instance of class `Category`.

However, in this case you can only classify `Article` to a single `Category`. So one thing you could do - if there is a limited number of category combinations - is create instances of class `Category` which stores the combinations of category names in a property of type `string[]`.

Comment: How would that work properly though? A lot of these articles have for example ["a", "b", "c"], but if I categorize the article has this one instance, then would it properly be found if I search for like class "a"?

Comment: You can search for articles using a `where` filter:
```where { operator: Equal, path: ["ofCategory", "Category", "name"], valueString: "a"}```. The where filter will return articles that have category "a" in the list of strings in property `name`.